# Using Static IP in HttpWebRequest.Create() with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

i have to reach a web site content which have an url like that :

```
90.245.10.221/page.php
```

When i try to run this code in ASP.NET:

```
WebRequest objRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse();
```

I have an error message like that:

> `System.UriFormatException`: Format of the URI could not be determined.

I think this url has a static IP. How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the protocol string in front of it, in this case I assume it's http://, so you would have your URL as http://90.245.10.221/page.php.

There is more information available on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6c2z492%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) as to possible issues with Uri construction